# Magento 2: Disable redirection to product page if requested quantity is not available on add to cart function

Tags: addtocart, catalog, inventory

On catalog category page, when I add any product to cart and the requested quantity is not available, it redirects to product page and shows error message there.
[image: Error message image on product]

What I want is to display error message while staying on the same page, instead of opening the product page.

Comment: Your product qty available in backed right?

Comment: @MohitPatel Yes, qty is available in the backend, but not enough. Like if the quantity is 10 in the backend and the user tries to add 20 to the cart, on a category page. Then it takes the user to the product page and displays an error there. I simply want to disable this redirection.